# Can I travel within the Schengen area while my TIE card in Spain is being renewed?

Tags: schengen-visas, spain, visa-renewals

I am a Filipina living in Spain on a student visa. My TIE's renewal is still being processed. I already received a favorable response and I already have my appointment at the end of February.

However, I am scheduled to go to Switzerland the first week of February. I already have a Regreso just in case, but I am still worried.

Comment: When does your current visa or residence permit expire?

Comment: It expired on the 30th of June 2023. I submitted my documents for renewal the next month July 3rd of 2023. But I only recently got a Favorable on December 2023. It was difficult to get an appointment for the TIE and I finally secured one but on the 29th of February.